# Simple Ruby 'or' question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

In console:

```
@user.user_type = "hello"
@user.user_type == "hello"
  true
@user.user_type == ("hello" || "goodbye")
  false
```

How do I write the last statement so it checks to see if `@user.user_type` is contained in one of the two strings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
["hello", "goodbye"].include? @user.user_type
```

Comment: I'm getting undefined method includes? for ["application/jpg", "application/png"]. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually, it's "include?". But @sscirrus, you should check the docs: http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Tokland. I was looking for the right source but a few minutes of Googling didn't find it. `include?` works correctly. +1!

Comment: My bad, only one coffee this morning 8)

Comment: Just in case you're curious, the creator of the programming language prefers 2nd person singular or 3rd person plural over 3rd person singular.

Answer (score 7):

`Enumerable#include?` is the idiomatic and simple way to go, but as a side note let me show you a very trivial extension that (I imagine) will please Python fans:

```
class Object
  def in?(enumerable)
    enumerable.include?(self)
  end
end

2.in? [1, 2, 3]  # true
"bye".in? ["hello", "world"] # false
```

Sometimes (most of the time, actually) it's semantically more fitting to ask if an object is inside a collection than the other way around. Now your code would look:

```
@user.user_type.in? ["hello", "goodbye"]
```

BTW, I think what you were trying to write was:

```
@user.user_type == "hello" || @user.user_type == "goodbye"
```

But we programmers are lazy by nature so better use `Enumerable#include?` and friends.

Comment: Awesome. A lot of valuable info in this answer.