# Ruby - alternative style for determining if object is contained within a list?

Tags: ruby

Let's say you have a conditions with multiple ORs, e.g.

```
if action == 'new' || action == 'edit' || action == 'update'
```

Another way to write this is:

```
if ['new', 'edit', 'action'].include?(action)
```

but that feels like a 'backwards' way to write the logic.

Is there any built-in way to do something like:

```
if action.equals_any_of?('new', 'edit', 'action')
```

?

Update - I'm quite keen on this little snippet:

```
class Object
  def is_included_in?(a)
    a.include?(self)
  end
end
```

Update 2 - improvements based on the comments below:

```
class Object
  def in?(*obj)
    obj.flatten.include?(self)
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not much of a Ruby dev, but I like the second one (it's what I'd do in JavaScript).

Comment: Perhaps `is_included_in?(*a)` would be more error-proof.

Comment: yeah, that's handy, I usually write a shorter `Object#in?`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421030/188031

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a regex?

```
action =~ /new|edit|action/
```

Or:

```
action.match /new|edit|action/
```

Or just write a simple utility method that's semantically-meaningful in the context of your app.

Comment: I like this. If I was dealing with strings I'd use this, wish there was something as concise for other objects.

Comment: @AndyWaite If you're dealing with an app-specific object (not really clear from the question) then the "simply utility method" meaningful to your app is likely the best option.

Answer (score 5):

Yet another way would be

```
case action
when 'new', 'edit', 'action'
  #whatever
end
```

You can also use a regular expression for a case like this

```
if action =~ /new|edit|action/
```

Comment: It's a bit more verbose but I think would be good in some situations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `%w` notation for arrays of strings:

```
%w(new edit action).include? action
```

Comment: Yeah, but that still seems backwards, i.e. the opposite how how you would describe the purpose of that line.