# What is a more readable way to test for one of three strings?

Tags: ruby, code-readability

Is there a more readable way to test if `delivery_status` is one of three strings?

```
if ["partial", "successful", "unsuccessful"].include? delivery_status
```

Here's what I'd really like, but it doesn't work:

```
if delivery_status == ("partial" or "successful" or "unsuccessful")
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421030/188031

Comment: That's a great idea @tokland about object.in?

Answer (score 3):

While I would **not** advise this, you can do it anyway:

```
def String
  def is_one_of?(array)
    array.include?(self)
  end
end
```

And then:

```
if delivery_status.is_one_of?([...])
```

But there is a much better solution: use case (if possible in your situation):

```
case delivery_status
when 'partial', 'successful', 'unsuccessful'
  #stuff happens here
when ... #other conditions
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if %w[partial successful unsuccessful].include? delivery_status
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not intuitive, but using the Regexp engine can speed these tests up:

```
STATES = ["partial", "successful", "unsuccessful"]
regex = /\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(STATES).source })\b/i
=> /\b(?:partial|successful|unsuccessful)\b/i

delivery_status = 'this is partial'
!!delivery_status[regex]
=> true

delivery_status = 'that was successful'
!!delivery_status[regex]
=> true

delivery_status = 'Yoda says, "unsuccessful that was not."'
!!delivery_status[regex]
=> true

delivery_status = 'foo bar'
!!delivery_status[regex]
=> false
```

If I'm not searching a string for the word, I'll use a hash for a lookup:

```
STATES = %w[partial successful unsuccessful].each_with_object({}) { |s, h| h[s] = true }
=> {"partial"=>true, "successful"=>true, "unsuccessful"=>true}
STATES['partial']
=> true
STATES['foo']
=> nil
```

Or use:

```
!!STATES['foo']
=> false
```

If you want a value besides true/nil/false:

```
STATES = %w[partial successful unsuccessful].each_with_index.with_object({}) { |(s, i), h| h[s] = i }
=> {"partial"=>0, "successful"=>1, "unsuccessful"=>2}
```

That'll give you `0`, `1`, `2` or `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something similar to @Linuxios's suggestion

```
class String
  def is_one_of(*these)
    these.include? self
  end

  def is_not_one_of(*these)
    these.include? self ? false : true
  end
end
```

This allows me to write:

```
if delivery_status.is_one_of "partial", "successful", "unsuccessful"
```

Comment: Hi @Mark. Note that usually the OP updates the question instead of creating his own answer.

Comment: Thanks @tokland this felt like more than just a little addendum. I was providing an answer to my own question so I added it as an answer.